# Normal Approximation versus MAP in pymc

Tags: statistics, distribution, probability, normal-distribution, pymc

Can anyone explain to me what does Normal Approximation do over and above what is done by MAP in some easy words?

I have read enough on http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelfitting.html#normal-approximations
but it is too complicated for me.

An example showing the difference will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAP simply returns a posterior mode, while the NormalApproximation uses a quadratic Taylor series approximation to the posterior, and so can return both the expected value and the covariance matrix. Of course, it uses a normal distribution to approximate the posterior, which may not be appropriate.